# got error in a pandas function while using this function groupby().mean

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

```
import pandas as pd
# Assuming df is my DataFrame
data = {
    'Make': ['Toyota', 'Honda', 'Toyota', 'BMW', 'Nissan', 'Toyota', 'Honda', 'Honda', 'Toyota', 'Nissan'],
    'Colour': ['White', 'Red', 'Blue', 'Black', 'White', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Blue', 'White', 'White'],
    'Odometer (KM)': [150043, 87899, 32549, 11179, 213095, 99213, 45698, 54738, 60000, 31600],
    'Doors': [4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
    'Price': ['$4,000.00', '$5,000.00', '$7,000.00', '$22,000.00', '$3,500.00', '$4,500.00', '$7,500.00', '$7,000.00', '$6,250.00', '$9,700.00']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Group by "Make" and calculate the mean for each numeric column
result = df.groupby("Make").mean()

# Display the result
print(result)
```

this is my code and there was no mistake in this code as it follows pandas documentation and follow all the rules but it stills gives error and if i give any 'char' in mean then its working fine and gives right answer like below code     "everything tested in jupyter notebook"

```
import pandas as pd

# Assuming df is my DataFrame
data = {
    'Make': ['Toyota', 'Honda', 'Toyota', 'BMW', 'Nissan', 'Toyota', 'Honda', 'Honda', 'Toyota', 'Nissan'],
    'Colour': ['White', 'Red', 'Blue', 'Black', 'White', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Blue', 'White', 'White'],
    'Odometer (KM)': [150043, 87899, 32549, 11179, 213095, 99213, 45698, 54738, 60000, 31600],
    'Doors': [4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
    'Price': ['$4,000.00', '$5,000.00', '$7,000.00', '$22,000.00', '$3,500.00', '$4,500.00', '$7,500.00', '$7,000.00', '$6,250.00', '$9,700.00']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Group by "Make" and calculate the mean for each numeric column
result = df.groupby("Make").mean('dhshsdhs')

# Display the result
print(result)
```

how this code is working fine ?

i tried the right way of coding as mentioned in pandas documentation and gets error and when doing the code wrong way its giving me right result.

Answer (score 0):

[`groupby.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.mean.html) accepts a `numeric_only` parameter which is `False` by default.

This is what triggers your error when running `df.groupby('Make').mean()` since your have strings in some columns (e.g. `'White'` in `Colour` or `'$4,000.00'` in `Price`), not numbers.

**By passing a random string as parameter you just set `numeric_only=True`** since the boolean value of `'dhshsdhs'` is `True`.

As a side note, if you want to compute the mean of the Price, first convert to numeric:

```
(df.assign(Price=lambda d: pd.to_numeric(d['Price'].str.replace(r'[$,]', '', regex=True)))
   .groupby('Make').mean(numeric_only=True)
)
```

Output:

```
        Odometer (KM)  Doors    Price
Make                                 
BMW      11179.000000   5.00  22000.0
Honda    62778.333333   4.00   6500.0
Nissan  122347.500000   4.00   6600.0
Toyota   85451.250000   3.75   5437.5
```